# Visual Studio 2022 How to Remove a Respository

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have a Visual Studio 2022 solution with 2 projects: the application itself and its Setup Project. These are circled in red in the attached image; the are 'Bridgemate Simulator Core' and 'Bridgemate Simulator Core Setup' . It used to have a third project called 'Bridgemate Simulator'. I removed the third project by right clicking on it in Solution Explorer and selecting 'Remove'.

'Bridgemate Simulator' and 'Bridgemate Simulator Core' were held in separate Git Repositories.

However when I view the Git Repositories (ctrl+0, ctrl+r) I see that the repository for the removed project has not been removed. See blue circled text.

How do I remove this repository from the solution ?

[image: Screenshot from Visual Studio]